# Events inside UITableViewCell not working below y value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm having some trouble getting my buttons to work below a certain y value in my table cells. I'm using a custom UITableViewCell class named "RowWhiskyContent". The default height is 44px and it's below that point my events don't seem to trigger anymore. The button displays just fine and so does everything else below that point, the event however don't seem to trigger. If i place my button half way (like at y=35) only the top part of the button triggers the event and the bottom part doesn't do a thing.

Here's the code trimmed down to the esentials:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell  *cell = nil;

    if(![self createView:&cell])
    {
        UIImage *bottle = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_add.png"]; //image size: 22x22
        UIButton *bottleButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 70, bottle.size.width, bottle.size.height)]; 

        [bottleButton setImage:bottle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:bottleButton];
        [bottleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addToCollection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 160);
        //cell.frame = cell.contentView.frame; // Tried this, didn't work.
        //[tableView reloadData]; // Tried this too, didn't work either.
    }
    return cell;
}

// Check if cell exists and create the cell if it doesn't.
-(BOOL) createView: (UITableViewCell**) cell
{
    BOOL cellExists = YES;
    *cell = (RowWhiskyContent *) [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentIdentifier"];    
    if(*cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RowWhiskyContent" owner:self options:nil];
        *cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        cellExists = NO;
    }
    return cellExists;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return 160;
}
```

Since I'm setting the height of the cell and the contentView both at 160 I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Reloading the data didn't work and neither did setting the cell.frame.

Could anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Added a screenshot:

[image]

Red button works fine but if I place it at the position of the green button it stops working. The contentview's background is set to purple so that explains the purple area. When clicking the cell it triggers the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so I'm guessing the the cell itself is also big enough.

Comment: It sounds like the controls that are not responding are being obscured by something OR more likely a containing views's frame is not being set correctly and although your control is being drawn it is sitting outside a parent view.

Because some cells are working I would first look at the table itself and any container views it sits in to see if part of the table sits 'outside a parent views frame.

Comment: did you set both delegates for table?

Comment: try setting tableView.clipsToBounds to YES so you'll see where your real active view sits

Comment: @rokjarc, not sure what it's supposed to do but I'm not seeing anything different.

@NeverBe, yes

@Damo, I'm not 100% what you mean with your comment, but I made a screenshot of the situation (added to question). The buttons don't seem to overlap. The purple area is the view (background color purple) and when I click anywhere in the purple area I trigger the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of the table cell so I'm guessing my table row has the same height.

Comment: @Ilians: it was according to Damo's comment - if there would be difference in appearance then you'd know your problem is in frame. Now you know it isn't :) Two things come to mind (i had simmiliar problem): A) do you have any semi-transparent view over it? B) Are you sure your touchscreen works ok at that area?

Comment: Not using a (semi-)transparent view and the touchscreen works fine since it does trigger the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of the table cell it's in.

Comment: try to replace [cell.contentView addSubview:bottleButton];  with [cell addSubview:bottleButton];

Comment: Adding the button to the cell instead of the view didn't work either.

Comment: You could use `NSLog(@"cell: %@", [cell.contentView recursiveDescription])` to display the different layers and elements inside your cell's contentView. Perhaps that shows some differences between the two buttons.

Comment: Logging `[cell.contentView recursiveDescription]` didn't show any difference between different buttons. It just showed the UIView and the UIButtons inside of it. Nothing overlapping or weird showing.

Comment: You could try adding the UIView debugging suite [DCIntrospect](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect). Try activating it and then clicking on/around the non-working button. If there's any view above the button, DCIntrospect should identify it (regardless of if it's structured to the cell, tableview, or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a content size issue.  Your button will display outside of the frame similar to overflow in CSS, however they will not respond to events.  So whatever UIView is containing your UIButton you need to make sure that it's content/frame/bounds are all set tall enough.  You can also use [cell.contentView sizeToFit] to adjust it automatically to it's content.

You should definitely NOT reload data inside of the protocol methods for your UITableView.

Comment: For unknown reasons the view order of the cell was like this: UITableViewCell->UIView->UIView. The UITableViewCell.contentView was using the last UIView leaving making it larger than the one containing it. The cell was the right size, the contentView (last UIView) was the right size but the in between view wasn't. Managed to solve it by making the UIView and the contentView the same UIView.